# Помогите разобраться с «Весёлым Роджером» и «Адамовым черепом»

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Что ещё интересно: всякое распятие хранит на себе «череп Адама». Этот
>   знак хорошо знаком нам – мы называем его «Весёлый Роджер», и первое, что
>   приходит в голову, это пиратский флаг. Скрещённые кости и череп на
>   чёрном фоне. И этот знак лежит под каждым Распятием. Даже на
>   нательных крестах. Череп Адама – это знак того, что Христос искупил
>   его грехи. Принёс себя в жертву за детей Адама. И по преданию, казнён
>   был на его могиле и кровь его омыла череп, даровав тем нам спасение.
>   Но ни в одной из версий этой фрески мы не видим, можно сказать,
>   основополагающей части рассказа. Всякий раз в изножье креста Христа на
>   место черепа Адама приходится круглое окно.

Я не знаю, как с этим справиться.

Вики просит не путать [Адамову голову](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB)) с ["Весёлым Роджером"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%91%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80)...

*Всякое распятие хранит на себе «череп Адама»,* - всякое ли? хранит на себе? а кавычки?

*Этот знак лежит под каждым Распятием. Даже на нательных крестах,* - так ли?

*Всякий раз в изножье креста Христа на место черепа Адама приходится круглое окно,* - так ли?

*Изножье креста* - можно ль?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Всякое распятие хранит на себе «череп Адама»

Да.

> всякое ли?

Каноническое. Новоделы, естественно, нарушают все канононы.

> хранит на себе?

Ну если автор выбрал этот оборот...

> Этот знак лежит под каждым Распятием. Даже на нательных крестах,

Не "даже" - а в первую очередь.

> а кавычки?

факультативно.

> Всякий раз в изножье креста Христа на место черепа Адама приходится круглое окно,

Не понимаю. Какое еще окно? на месте черепа??? И вообще - кто на ком стоял?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новодел, но выглядит более или менее канонично.
Где тут окно?!